# Why isn't everyone using Felix Felicis ("Liquid Luck")?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

First I must say I never read the *Harry Potter* books and maybe the answer lays there, but it always bothered me that the liquid luck is so powerfull and yet rarely used.  Why isn't everyone using it since it is so powerful and anyone that would use it would have a great advantage in a fight, a debate or anything really?

Even if it is really hard to create the benefits seems likely to be greater than the time and effort to make some.

I tried to look for an answer but didn't stumble onto one that satisfied my curiosity. Nonetheless I am open to redirection to articles/blogs I could have missed.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Felix_Felicis

Comment: Essentially, it's a drug...and bad things happen with drugs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is really adressed in the movies at all. This seems to be more of a general question about the workings of the *Harry Potter* universe that might be better served on [scifi.se].

Comment: All right I can understand that it has side effects and that it could kill you. But if I was Voldemort or any bad guy really why would I want to play it fair ? I mean before every really important battle I would take some. Paulie_D in the link you give it is really useful everytime and the side effects are nothing compared to the benefits.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Funnily enough, I'm *certain* that this (or a similar question) has been asked on SciFi.SE before. I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Not *exactly* the same question, but very similar: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23267/why-doesnt-either-side-in-the-wizarding-war-use-felix-felicis

Comment: What happens if two people using it end up fighting each other? :)

Comment: @Dave Maybe you should ask that as a separate question. (Yeah, I'm joking, please don't.) ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson He doesn't have to. [SciFi.SE has that one covered as well.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116200/what-would-happen-in-a-battle-of-felix-felicises)

Comment: Colour me unspurprised. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no answer in the movies but there are answers in the books, making it more of a Harry Potter Universe question suitable for SF&F.SE, where it has been asked and answered.